# Error when trying to deploy Azure Function App via local-exec in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy my Function to my Function App via the local-exec method on Terraform. My code looks like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "code_deploy" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group ${data.azurerm_resource_group.Resource_Group.name} --name ${var.name} --src ${var.src}"
  }
  depends_on = ["azurerm_function_app.Function"]
}
```

However, whenever I try to run it, I always get the following error:

```
null_resource.code_deploy: Error running command 'az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group resource-group-name --name code-name --src sourcefile.zip': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: az: command not found
```

Pretty sure I am already authenticated to Azure via the following:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=1.44.0"
  subscription_id = "${var.SubscriptionID}"
  tenant_id       = "${var.TenantID}"
}
```

If it helps, my Azure provider version is 1.44.0 and my Terraform version is 0.11.15.

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

probably because , from the vm/laptop which you are trying to execute terraform does not have az cli installed or configured.

Comment: Apologies for the noob question, but any idea how to install or configure the CLI via terraform? I've tried to follow this https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360063145593-How-to-install-the-Azure-CLI-in-Terraform, but it just gives me different errors saying that the commands aren't found.

Comment: that article looks correct me , i hope resource "null_resource" "install_azure_cli"  is executed before resource "null_resource" "code_deploy" which is by adding depends_on 


depends_on = ["azurerm_function_app.Function"
"null_resource", "install_azure_cli"]

Comment: I've already done that, but I get the following errors: "null_resource.install_azure_cli (local-exec): /bin/sh: line 2: sudo: command not found", "null_resource.install_azure_cli (local-exec): gpg: [stdout]: write error: Broken pipe", "null_resource.install_azure_cli (local-exec): gpg: iobuf_flush failed on close: Broken pipe", "null_resource.install_azure_cli (local-exec): /bin/sh: line 7: lsb_release: command not found". Any idea what's causing these?

Comment: i am assuming you are using ubuntu linux to execute terraform and install aws cli , if it rhel/centos then you need to change the script as per rhel/centos, because script is written for ubuntu linux